# Give me one example for import and export procedures?

Tags: sas

I am from new to SAS, so i wnaat to learn import and export procedures.So could any one please help me ,how can i know this task?

Answer (score 3):

You should have mentioned the specific task you need to perform and what have you tried and what problems have you encountered.

In its current form, your question is best answered by linking to the PROC IMPORT documentation ("[Examples: IMPORT Procedure](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000308091.htm)").